# Good introductions to time series (with R)

Tags: r, time-series, references

I am currently collecting data for an experiment into psychosocial characteristics associated with the experience of pain. As part of this, I am collecting GSR and BP measurements electronically from my participants, along with various self-report and implicit measures. I have a psychological background and am comfortable with factor analysis, linear models and experimental analysis.

My question is what are good (preferably free) resources available for learning about time series analysis. I am a total newb when it comes to this area, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I have some pilot data to practice on, but would like to have my analysis plan worked out in detail before I finish collected data.

If the provided references were also R related, that would be wonderful.

Edited: to change grammar and to add 'self report and implicit measures'

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a very large subject and there are many good books that cover it.  These are both good, but Cryer is my favorite of the two:

1. Cryer. "[Time Series Analysis: With Applications in R](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387759581)" is a classic on the subject, updated to include R code.
2. Shumway and Stoffer. "[Time Series Analysis and Its Applications: With R Examples](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387293175)".

A good free resource is [Zoonekynd's ebook, especially the time series section](http://zoonek2.free.fr/UNIX/48_R/15.html).

My first suggestion for seeing the R packages would be the free ebook ["A Discussion of Time Series Objects for R in Finance"](https://www.rmetrics.org/ebooks-tseries) from Rmetrics.  It gives lots of examples comparing the different time series packages and discusses some of the considerations, but it doesn't provide any theory.

Eric Zivot's ["Modeling financial time series with S-PLUS"](http://books.google.com/books?id=sxODP2l1mX8C) and Ruey Tsay's "[Analysis of Financial Time Series](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471690740)" (available in the TSA package on CRAN) are directed and financial time series but both provide good general references.  I strongly recommend looking at [**Ruey Tsay's homepage**](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/) because it covers all these topics, and provides the necessary R code.  In particular, look at the ["Analysis of Financial Time Series"](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/bs41202/sp2009/), and ["Multivariate Time Series Analysis"](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/mts/sp2009/) courses.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the Zoonekynd reference, i found that before but couldnt get back to it.

Comment: I had never seen Zoonekynd before, it is great!

Answer (score 6):

[Time Series Analysis and Its Applications: With R Examples](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa3/) by Robert H. Shumway and David S. Stoffer would be a great resource for the subject, but you may find a lot of useful blog entries (e.g. my favorite one: [learnr](http://learnr.wordpress.com/)) and tutorials (e.g. [from the linked homepage](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/R_time_series_quick_fix.htm)) also on the Internet freely available .

On David Stoffer's homepage (linked above) you can find the example datasets used in the book's chapters, and others from the first and second editions with even sample chapters also.

Comment: Thank you for the links, the one to this PDF looks especially useful http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Farnsworth-EconometricsInR.pdf Not sure how i missed that.

Comment: I don't think that the LearnR blog has any time series references...

Comment: I searched it for time-series, and got some stuff about ggplot2. Useful, but not really with i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Very late answer from me, but I have found [Introductory Time Series with R](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introductory-Time-Series-Paul-Cowpertwait/dp/0387886974) by Cowpertwaite and Metcalfe to be really useful for transitioning between BSc level analysis to MSc level stuff and professional work. Yes, it is a little basic, but there's good explanations and examples and some useful code.

EDIT: I should add that I've also found Cryer and Chan hugely useful too in line with the first answer.