# Better understanding of GARCH and ARCH models

Tags: time-series, garch

I want to make a function that does GARCH and ARCH in python for calculating variance. But I only have a general understanding of the model. Are there any good papers that can be recommend to give me a step by step calculation. I am not a statistician or have a econometrics background so it is difficult for me to get a detailed understanding.

Right now my understanding is:

Input: Error terms, alpha values, beta values, orders p and q

Error terms are from the difference between the best fit Autoregressive model and the actual data. (not sure if this is correct). The error at time t is made up of 2 terms a standard deviation at time t and a stochastic variable.

q is the ARCH term used for squared of errors. p is the used for variance.

Alpha is a 1 x q length matrix and beta 1 x p length matrix. Both are coefficients larger than 0 and less than 1. (not sure how they are calculated)
Alpha represents internal volatility (not sure if this is correct)
Beta represents external volatility(not sure if this is correct)

Output: variance at time t

Statistics Test:

Jarque-Bera test: Checks if the error terms are normal distributed

White test:  checks for heteroskedasticity in error terms

Wald test: used to check how alpha and beta influence the time series (not sure if this is correct)

Lagrange multiplier test: determines the order of the model (not sure if this is correct)

Comment: Have you tried reading some [time series textbooks](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20514)? Or help files of functions implementing ARCH/GARCH models in your favorite statistical software package ([vignette of `rugarch`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rugarch/vignettes/Introduction_to_the_rugarch_package.pdf) in R is quite good)?

Comment: You can find my time series notes in this link, there is a extensive and I believe reader friendly chapter on ARCH family: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pl0qQZjbKopfQb00Jo-50u01D7c5ZlyO/view?usp=sharing