# textbooks/literature/resources for online learning/ time series/ sequential analysis?

Tags: time-series, self-study, references, online-algorithms, sequential-analysis

I have read (the contents page of) machine learning introductory textbooks such as Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, Machine Learning A Probabilistic Perspective, and The Elements of Statistical Learning.

But it seems there's not much about online learning and sequential data (except for HMMs and filtering algorithms).

Which textbooks/literature/resource should be a good starting point to learn about online learning/ time series/ sequential analysis (assumed I have a basic understanding of machine learning)?

**Update**
I've found an open source project (together with a paper) by Facebook, [prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/), which looks really nice.

Comment: Please focus on a single topic, since you mention three topics that are more or less unrelated. Moreover there are several threads that answer your questions, e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20514/books-for-self-studying-time-series-analysis