# Books or tutorials for GARCH(1,1)

Tags: time-series, references, simulation, garch

I would like to use GARCH(1,1) to simulate $n$ samples. I really need to understand it deeply, so are there any good book or tutorials that can help?

Comment: There are two very different questions in your post; I would advise posting them separately. But please review the existing threads before you proceed. You might very well find your questions have already been answered there.

Comment: See [Books for self-studying time series analysis?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20514/books-for-self-studying-time-series-analysis).

Comment: ["Books on Bayesian inferential analysis of GARCH models"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385597) is a related thread.

Answer (score 2):

Rather comprehensive and advanced:

- Francq, Christian, and Jean-Michel Zakoian. [*GARCH Models: Structure, Statistical Inference and Financial Applications*](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470683910.html). John Wiley & Sons, 2010.

There is a [second edition](https://www.wiley.com/en-no/GARCH+Models:+Structure,+Statistical+Inference+and+Financial+Applications,+2nd+Edition-p-9781119313489) from 2019.

Comment: I have flagged the question for turning it into Community Wiki, and I suggest one reference per answer.