# Best ML method/algorithm for prediction of varying data?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

As the title says, I'm looking for a **Machine Learning method/algorithm that can help me predict a dataset in the future.**

I only have about 100 data points and would like to predict as *far in the future as I can*, being...say..less than 20% off from the actual data. e.g. if the data in the future is 100, then my prediction should be from somewhere from 80 to 120.

Of course, This data is daily, so as you can imagine, it varies quite a lot. e.g. one day the datapoint is ~ 180 and the next it's ~ 1200. I don't think there will be a very accurate method for this kind of data, but I have to try.

I have multiple other datasets that are [closely]/[almost directly] related to this dataset. I would like to use those datasets to maybe try and have a closer prediction, if there is such a method.

Another thing, **I am a newcomer** to machine learning, and tried my best to think of ways to predict the data. I thought of neural networks, but realized it wouldn't even apply to the problem. For now, I just have a basic polynomial regression model. Basically fitting a curve to the data and looking at the curve to predict what the data will be, which seems quite basic and..not accurate.

Thanks,
WhipStreak23

Comment: [tag:time-series] analysis focuses on data that are arranged temporally. It's a large topic. Without a more specific question, it's hard to say what kinds of models may be appropriate.

Comment: building off of that -- this depends almost entirely on the structure of your dataset, as well as the specific prediction task -- hard to give guidance without that information.

Comment: This is COVID-19 data, the data I'm trying to predict is how many new cases per day there will be and the other related datasets are the number of new hospitalized people, new deaths, etc.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica Does the information I gave yesterday, help?

Comment: This doesn't really do anything to specify a particular problem. The best suggestion I can give you is the recommendation to start reading about time series analysis from a high-quality textbook.

Comment: Don't have a textbook :(. Don't want to bother you more, but are there sources online which you know are very good and comprehensive?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20514/books-for-self-studying-time-series-analysis

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you could try to use the LSTM, which is a deep neural network from a particular class of networks called Recurrent Neural Networks. The LSTM is quite powerful for forecasting several types of time series.

You could start with this tutorial from TensorFlow:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series

Best,
Sergio Novi

Comment: Thanks Sergio, though I was looking for a tutorial in R, you pointed where I need to look. Thanks.