# Do I need to have studied econometrics to do time series analysis?

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, references, econometrics

I have an undergrad degree in Economics and Management but my academic training/background in econometrics is insufficient, although I did study micro/macro economics and fundamental math and statistics for economics. I still struggle with advance math and statistics topics and do not have sufficient background in econometrics. I want to be able to do time series analysis and forecasting professionally. Is it possible for me? Any recommendations (books/resources) would be highly appreciated.

Comment: During your academic training, you not only learned the specific subject matter of your classes, but you also learned 1) how to learn and 2) the kinds of things that you are capable of learning. There's plenty of material on the internet, the hard part is sitting down and forcing yourself to study it. FWIW, my favorite text on time series is Hamilton's, but that may be too advanced; just start with material available for free on the web.

Comment: Seconding @JohnMadden, I would also advocate for Hamilton for the early chapters are quite easy paced and introductory. It gets more advanced later which at the first read, one can skip. The beauty is that the material is dense and self-contained.

Comment: Coming to OP's query, we were introduced to time series in econometrics paper. But you can study time series independently without delving into the theoretical framework at the outset: Chatfield would be a good intro. However, I would urge to look into Rob Hyndman's [FPP3](https://otexts.com/fpp3/) for grasping the flavor of forecasting with little prerequisite.

Comment: And also [Books for self-studying time series analysis?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20514/237901)

Comment: @User1865345 thank you! I have already been through RH Principles of Forecasting fpp3 - a great resource for beginners, however, I want to know how much of econometrics stuff I need to know to be able to perform more complex modelling and actually be really good at time series analysis and forecasting?

Comment: @ask9, to be frank, you can sail through mostly at ease without resorting to econometrics. We were taught about ARGH/GARCH, unit roots and Cointegration  in econometrics classes rather than time series. But you won't need to delve straight into them. First learn the basics of modelling, have some experience and then you can assess yourself what you need more to cover once you have the introductory insight.

Comment: I believe in learning layer by layer. Study should be based on stages. You can't grasp the advanced things at the first go. Learn slowly and gradually. Solidify your grasp over the basics. Then move according to the hierarchy. Once you have enough fuel, you can approach the advanced theoretical parts. It would be fruitful in the long run.

Comment: @User1865345 thanks! You are right about solidifying my grasp over basic modelling.  I should perhaps redo the exercises given in Principles of Forecasting by RH. I was also thinking that I could download data from other sources and using R perform forecast modelling and then host my work on GitHub and maybe get someone to look at my work. Thanks for your response!